# Hidden /Conditional fields in forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, hidden-field

Is it possible to display a form-field only if a specific condition is met?

I want to make something like:

```
<%= f.input :pregnancies, :as => :radio, :label => "Pregnancies", :collection => [["no", false], ["yes", true]]%>

if :pregnancies = true    

then show this input
<%= f.input :preg_nr, :label => "Number of pregnancies" %>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) can get you started

Comment: It's best to summarize rather than provide *only* a link :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want this page to be dynamic? Where, if a user chooses 'Yes' for Pregnancies, then they are able to choose the number of pregnancies? If this is the case I think you will want to use some type of client side code...something like Javascript or JQuery. Unfortunately my skills are limited here. Hopefully someone will chime in with a code sample for you.